# Tool to online automatically evaluate students assignments

Tags: java, web-browser

I'm a Computer Science professor and will teach Java in this semester.

I'm looking for a site, a software, or a tool, that my students could submit their work (submitting all class files) online.

The tool would run their program, with some tests as input, generate their output, and compare this output with the outputs of the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly what you need is available as a part of [Project Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/) as [NBGrader](https://github.com/jupyter/nbgrader) see the [documentation](https://nbgrader.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for more details.

- Allows students to take tests online including coding in a number of languages.
- Free & Open Source + cross platform.
- Tests can include check data that the students can execute, within the test, their own code on.
- Tests can include both Automatic and Manual Marked questions.
- More

You can either use a central server or other mechanisms such as email for distributing & gathering the tests.

https://youtu.be/5WUm0QuJdFw for a video presentation on NBGrader.